# SQL Database with XML fields, select according to XElement using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table in an SQL database, where the table configuration corresponds to

```
ID
Name string
data xml
```

where the datafield might (but not necessarily) contain a descendant element

```
<config>Some value...</config>
```

Using LINQ I want to select all the rows that has a data xml element which contains the config element with a value of... say 17.

My approach has been something like:

```
var query = from x in db
            from y in x.data.descendants("config")
            where y.Value == "17"
            select x;
```

But this throws an exception about the Value not being valid.

How should I formulate this query?

Regards, Casper

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can LINQ to SQL query an XML field DB-serverside?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282391/can-linq-to-sql-query-an-xml-field-db-serverside)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Linq 2 SQL does not support what you are trying to do. You would probably need to write a custom SQL statement or use a user defined function as discussed in the solution to this SO question: [Can LINQ to SQL query an XML field DB-serverside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282391/can-linq-to-sql-query-an-xml-field-db-serverside)