# Which ORM can query XML in the database

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc-2, orm

I am planning to store XML in the database and looking for an ORM that can easily query values in the database. I will be using SQL Server 2008 or MySQL depending on the XML support. Can you give your thoughts or advice on which tool is best for this.

Comment: You might like to shed some light on what you plan to do with the XML once stored... Perhaps you want the SQL engine itself to query an XML field with a certain XPath? Perhaps you just want to CRUD some XML stored within a field?

Comment: LINQ to SQL and EF do not, but there are workarounds: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/282391/can-linq-to-sql-query-an-xml-field-db-serverside

Comment: Yes, I will be performing CRUD operations. I will need to query an xml column to see if a tag has a certain attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to SQL can do so... [see this](http://conficient.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/querying-xml-fields-in-linq-to-sql/)